# FileNotFoundException is thrown from memory mapped file OpenExisting

Tags: c#

I would like to create the memory mapped file between custom module and web services deployed in IIS. What I am implementation is like below

1. First, create the memory mapped file from module / web service.
2. Then open that existing file from web app and update the value to memory mapped file according to some conditions
3. Then read the value from memory mapped from custom module.

Sometimes it works properly but sometimes FileNotFoundException is thrown from OpenExisting from web service side. Could anyone have ideas for my problems?

### Module

```
public class TestModuleMemory
{
    static MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = null;

    // Call whenever module is initialized
    public static void Start()
    {
       Create();
       Open();
    }
    // Create memory mapped file
    private static void Create()
    {
        MemoryMappedFileSecurity sec = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
        sec.AddAccessRule(new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(new 
        SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, 
         AccessControlType.Allow));
        MemoryMappedFile mappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(@"Global\TestMap", 1024, 
        MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, MemoryMappedFileOptions.None, mSec, HandleInheritability.Inheritable);      
    }

    // Open and create view accessor
    private static void Open()
    {
        MemoryMappedFile mappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.OpeningExisting(@"Global\TestMap", MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
        accessor = mappedFile.CreateViewAccessor();
    }
   
   // Call from begin request whenever request is accepted
   // Read from memory mapped file
   private static int Read()
   {
       accessor.ReadInt32(0);
   }
```

}

### Web Service

```
public class TestService
{
    static MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = null;

    public void Start()
    {
       try
       {
            MemoryMappedFile mappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.OpeningExisting(@"Global\TestMap", MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, HandleInheritability.Inheritable)
            accessor = mappedFile.CreateViewAccessor();
       }
       catch(FileNotFoundException)
       {
            // getting the error from here.
            // If new mapped file with same map name is created from, file is created without any error but that new created file is different from the one created by module.
       }
       
       while(condition)
       {
           if(condition)
           {
               int value = condition1 ? 0 : 1;
               accessor.Write(0,value);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really ought to ensure that you've always got a reachable (in GC terms) instance pointing to the file. Between the end of your `Create` method and until your `Open` method calls `OpenExisting`, you don't. Why are you creating a second instance rather than just creating the accessor directly from the one in `Create`?

Comment: I am sorry but could you please tell me how can I know whether I got a reachable instance or not?I changed the code to creating directly from the first instance without two instance. But it's still getting error. The mapped file created and data can be read properly from first process. But FileNotFoundException is still getting from second process.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a class level variable to prevent disposal of the MMF like the below:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile>            
            identifierMmfMap = new Dictionary<string, System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile>();
```

Add the MMF to this collection immediately after creating from Create() method of your code:

```
identifierMmfMap[@"Global\TestMap"] = mappedFile;
```